# Can a semi-colon be followed by and adverb and then a conjunction?

Tags: semicolons

In the following sentence, is the usage of the semi-colon correct?

> Developing techniques to describe this particular system is intractably difficult; mainly because there is no reference system from which it can be described.

Comment: Though a full stop and a sentence fragment would not be seen as totally unacceptable in all but the most formal of registers nowadays, use of the semicolon here is non-standard.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Would a comma be more appropriate?

Comment: @Edwin: I'd be quite happy with a semicolon there if we threw out the words ***mainly because***. Which for reasons I can't put my finger on, seem somewhat "colloquial" in context, and therefore at odds with the "formal" associations of using semicolons in such contexts.

Comment: No, it's not correct. You don't actually need any punctuation at all, though some would prefer a comma. "Because" is a preposition, so "mainly because there is no reference system from which it can be described" is not a subordinate clause but a preposition phrase.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Although you include a caveat about formal registers, I think it is important to advise anyone that "sentence fragments" that do not contain an active or passive main verb would be unlikely to be acceptable in a university essay; at least not in the UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *because* is a subordinating conjunction, making everything that follows a dependent clause. The word *mainly* modifies this entire clause, so the comma come appropriately just before it.

Semicolons join two *independent* clauses when there is no conjunction.